# Test Flutter Facebook Firebase Login

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I would like to test the `facebookLogin()` method on my app, but I can't set it properly.

[Code reference](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/social/#facebook)

This is my test :

```
test(
  "should return FirebaseUser when called loginWithFacebook",
  () async {
    // arrange
    when(mockFacebookLogin.login()).thenAnswer((realInvocation) async => tToken);
    when(FacebookAuthProvider.credential("token-id")).thenReturn(tCredential);
    // act
    final result = await repository.loginWithFacebook();
    // assert
    expect(result, Right(tFirebaseUser));
    verify(mockFacebookLogin.login());
  },
);
```

I get this error: `Bad state: No method stub was called from within 'when()'. Was a real method called, or perhaps an extension method?` on `when(FacebookAuthProvider.credential("token-id")).thenReturn(tCredential);`

I read that this error shows because I'm trying to mock a static method and I need to convert it to a non-static method.